# Event handlers jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I have this code below:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("button").off('click');  //detach click for the button below
}
```

Then in the `<body>` tag I have this button below

```
<button>PLAY ANIMATION</button>
```

So the question is where can I place this code below?

```
$("button").bind('click'); // In other words I want to 
//reattach the click event that I just disabled at some later point
```

Comment: Take a step back... what's the end-game here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a map animation and when a click event occurs on the button the animaaation plays. But while the animation is playing I do not want the user to click on the button. Only after the animation is done can they once again click the play button.

Comment: you could place it inside animation callback function..!

Comment: Reattach the event once the animation is complete then. "If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the animation is complete", However, use `.on` instead of `bind` - "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: I am able to do a hide then a show which is pretty close to what I want.

Comment: $("button").on('click');   //Does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2NNGv/1/

Also you can do `.is(":animated")` check!

[jQuery ajax, wait until beforeSend animation finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212949/jquery-ajax-wait-until-beforesend-animation-finishes)

Hope it fits the cause `:)` and gives you idea!

**Sample code**

```
$("button").click(function() {

    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');

    $('div').animate({
        marginLeft: "-200",
        marginTop: "-200",
        width: "400",
        height: "400"
        // Comment the line below to see difference
        ,
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 2000).animate({
        marginLeft: -150,
        marginTop: -150,
        width: 300,
        height: 300
        // Comment the line below to see difference
        ,
        opacity: 1
    }, 2000).show(function() {
        $("button").removeAttr('disabled');
    });

});​
```

Comment: Tats this is awesome but I should have mentioned it is a Leaflet animation of a weather radar loop.

Comment: This was a great example, however the only thing I could get to work was my second idea regarding hiding the button during the animation and then showing it again.

Comment: @gdoron oh bruv! Welcome Back! How you doing? **GREAT** to see you, you are back, I am doing fine! `:)` now! Now you are around SO will be full of awesomeness `:)` how was your holidays? Have a pint on me today will return you the $ `:)` whenever we meet!

Comment: @jimdif if you want to hide the button **Working Demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/FEk2j/ this should fit your need!

Comment: @Tats_innit. I'm still on a break has woke up at 4:30 AM... so... :)

Comment: @gdoron heh! oh darn! `:)` you busted the excitment ballon around SO now `:P` Have a coffee on me then < my shout >! LOL

Answer (score 1):

use `.promise()` to wait for the animation to finish, and attach the click event later.

see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/gkveX/

> Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a certain type
>   bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bind and unbind?

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
});

// will NOT work
$('#foo').unbind('click', function() {
  alert('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
});
```

Here is the source http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

You can bind the button then unbind it during the animation and then bind it again to enable the click event.